# I hope you'll recover

Tags: expressions

How to wish a sick person to recover from the illness? I'm interested in the expression for informal usage.

Answer (score 14):

The context is important. How sick is the person? Just a mild illness or a serious, life-threatening disease? How you write something will vary greatly depending on the answer.

For a mild illness, I would say something like

> I hope you'll be feeling better soon.

For a serious illness, where you know the person may not be 'feeling better soon', I'd say something like

> I'll be thinking of you and wishing you all the best for a swift recovery.

I would definitely NOT say "I hope you'll recover" as it carries the implication that the person is likely to die!

Answer (score 1):

How about

> Best wishes for a speedy recovery!

It's trite but works.

Comment: Or if conversationally spoken you could say 'I do hope you will be be much better soon'. I wouldn't say 'I hope you'll recover'. It infers that there is a possibility he or she may not.